# Python finally block not catching errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, debugging, error-handling

Take a look at a chunk of code:

```
move = [None, 20, 5, True, "a"]   
valnum = 0
    for val in move:
        try:
            if val >= 15:
                val -= 3
                move[valnum] = val
        finally:
            valnum += 1
print(move)
```

When run, it gives this error:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Isn't the whole point of the finally statement to avoid errors like this?

EDIT: Thank you for your help. I don't think I made myself clear enough in my question. After your suggestions, I coded it to this:

```
move = [None, 20, 5, True, "a", 19]   
valnum = 0
for val in move:
    try:
        if val >= 15:
            val -= 3
            move[valnum] = val
    except TypeError:
        valnum += 1
print(move)
```

And the output now becomes:

```
[None, 17, 16, True, 'a', 19]
```

It's easy to see what went wrong. The exception block only runs when there is an error, but I need the block to run no matter if there is an error or not. Is there a solution to this, other than just:

```
move = [None, 20, 5, True, "a", 19]   
valnum = 0
for val in move:
    try:
        if val >= 15:
            val -= 3
            move[valnum] = val
    except TypeError:
        valnum += 1
        continue
    valnum += 1
print(move)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not.

It is there to make sure something always gets executed, no matter if there is an exception or not. It does not catch the exception, for that you need an `except` block.

For example:

```
for val in move:
    try:
        if val >= 15:
            val -= 3
            move[valnum] = val
    except TypeError:
        valnum += 1
```

`finally` blocks are useful for things like resource cleanup, closing files, that sort of thing.

---

Based on the comment by Big Bird, here is how you would run the code and also ignore the error:

```
for val in move:
    try:
        if val >= 15:
            val -= 3
            move[valnum] = val
    except TypeError:
        pass  # catch the error and ignore it
    valnum += 1
```

---

Edited yet again, I realised *what* you wanted to do only now, since I'd been too focussed on *how* you were trying to do it. I suggest not caring about `valnum` at all, instead doing this:

```
move = [None, 20, 5, True, "a", 19]   
for index, val in enumerate(move):
    try:
        if val >= 15:
            val -= 3
            move[index] = val
    except TypeError:
        pass
print(move)
```

Comment: What if I want the valnum += 1 line to run no matter if there is an error or not in the try?

Comment: Please see my edited answer to take your comment into account.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is 'except' for handling that. Your code should look like:

```
move = [None, 20, 5, True, "a"]   
valnum = 0
for val in move:
    try:
        if val >= 15:
            val -= 3
            move[valnum] = val
    except TypeError:
        valnum += 1
print(move)
```

When you use `finally`, it means that the code inside `finally` will run after the try condition as a clean-up action.
You can check the documentation for more information on the `finally` action: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions

Looking at your code and use, you can simply

Comment: [Bare `except`s are considered harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948548/what-is-wrong-with-using-a-bare-except)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, had missed it

Comment: Thanks for the cleanup. But, what if I want the valnum += 1 line to run no matter if there is an error or not in the try?